# Is it possible to use std::sort to sort by lexicographic order?

Tags: c++, sorting

My problem looks like this:

1. At the beginning u have to insert an amount of numbers.
2. Next program counts the sum of digits of the number that u inserted in step one.
3. All scores are inserted in vector called vec

The problem is this: At the end of the program all numbers that You inserted in steps 1, must be sorted depends of theirs sums of digits(Sorting in increasing order).

And ATTENTION please! For example if two of numbers(e.g. 123 and 12300) have the same sum of digits you have to sort them by the lexicographic order.

I don't want to create function build by myself but I would like to use “sort” function from library  but I have problem with that..Is it possible to use sort function also to sorting by the lexicographic order?  Can someone can help me?
Example input:

```
6 
13
36
27
12
4
123
```

Expected output:

```
12
13
4
123
27
36
```

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > vec;
    int num;
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        vector<int> row;

        row.push_back(num);

        //conversion int to string:
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << num;
        string str = ss.str();

        int sum = 0;
        for (int g = 0; g < str.length(); g++){
            int pom = str[g] - '0';
            sum += pom;
        }

        row.push_back(sum);
        vec.push_back(row);
        row.clear();
    }

    //sort(vec[0][0], vec[vec.size()][0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            //cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << vec[i][0] << endl;
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're sorting by sum of digits, and lexicographically on same-sum, this shouldn't be a vector of `int`; it should be a vector of `std::string` with a custom comparator functor.

Comment: so do I have to convert vec before " //sort(vec[0][0], vec[vec.size()][0]);" command, to string or I have to rebuild the whole code?

Comment: You can achieve the same thing with a vector of numbers, no need for any text operations, @WhozCraig.

Comment: "lambda" you mean lambda expression?

Comment: Yes. Search the web, there are hundreds of examples out there that show how to provide a predicate to `std::sort()`, the default being `std::less`.

Comment: so far I have not had to deal with lambda expressions .. but i'll check it

Comment: You can use a lambda expression, but you don't have to. Most examples you will find will not use them either, probably because they weren't always a C++ feature.

Comment: No need for a custom comparator if you use `pair<int,string>`, see my answer.

Comment: @MarcinPiwko Walter is absolutely right. there is no need for a custom comparator if you tailor what is being sorted to do what you want regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store each number as a string, but also pre-compute its digit-sum and keep both in a `pair<int,string>`, then put them into a `vector<pair<int,string>` and `sort` it. **No need for a custom comparator**, the one for `std::pair` does exactly what you want.

```
// note: std::pair<std::string,int> would not work
typedef std::pair<int,std::string> number;
std::vector<number> numbers;

// fill numbers such that number::first holds the digit sum
// and number::second the number as string.
// this is similar to your code

std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

// now numbers are ordered as you want them
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace Whilst you pointed that out, I figured it out myself.

Comment: can you tell me what is the command which inserts the digit sum into vairable-number?

Comment: I've never used commands like typedef std::pair<int,std::string> number; that's why I am asking..

Comment: Did you miss #include <utility>  ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Nice way to set the `pair<int,string>` in your code. Didn't know that you do it like that.

Comment: @MarcinPiwko I only provided the bare skeleton with the idea that you work out the rest, but see full code by WhozCraig.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a suitable comparison function (or functor, e.g. a lambda would be natural) to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to compare on sum of digits first and then lexicographically to break ties, it will be convenient to convert your input numbers to strings.

From there you can define a custom comparator to achieve the desired behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int sumDigits(string s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i)
    {
        sum += s[i] - '0';
    }
    return sum;
}

bool digitSumComparator(int i, int j)
{
    int iSum = sumDigits(to_string(i));
    int jSum = sumDigits(to_string(j));
    if (iSum == jSum)
    {
        return iStr < jStr;
    }
    else
    {
        return iSum < jSum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v {6,13,36,27,12,4,123};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), digitSumComparator);
    for (vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout <<  *it << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 digitsumsort.cpp
$ ./a.out
12 13 4 123 6 27 36
```